# url("#{resource[...]}") in CSS files do not work in JSF 1.2

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-1.2

I am trying to add font-awesome to a JSF 1.2 project.

I edited all fonts in the font-awesome css files to be like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot']}?v=4.3.0");
    src: url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot']}?#iefix&v=4.3.0")
        format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2']}?v=4.3.0") format('woff2'),
        url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff']}?v=4.3.0") format('woff'),
        url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf']}?v=4.3.0")
        format('truetype'),
        url("#{resource['fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg']}?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular")
        format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal
}
```

But it's not working. I did the same to a JSF 2.2 project and it's working fine. Am I accessing the resources folder correctly, and if yes, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF 1.2 doesn't support `<h:outputStylesheet>` nor `#{resource}`. Those are JSF 2.x only.

Use `<link>` and hardcode the `url()` paths.

---

Beware: many many things were done differently and awkwardly in the jurassic JSF 1.x. If possible, migrate it to JSF 2.x as soon as possible. See also [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0). If not possible, make sure that you consult specifically JSF 1.x resources and not JSF 2.x ones while looking for answers.